# Como fazer a body ter um scroll

Tags: html

Como posso fazer a body de um site ter scroll, para os users poderem puxar a barra para baixo e para cima para verem toda a informação do site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Com css, tipo assim? 
100 vh pega e da a altura de 100 partes da tela, se passar disso irá colocar uma scroll na tela.

```css
body{
   overflow:auto;
  height: 100vh;
  }
```

Comment: Isso, mesmo tá ai a resposta. Daqui a 10 min já aceito a resposta.